# JavaScript / jQuery - Keep anchor tags in sliced paragraph text content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**The Scenario**

I have a description that contains links. If the description contains more than 100 characters I slice it to contain only text from the first character to the 100th character. I also show an ellipses and a More link which displays the rest of the content on click.

**The Issue**

When slicing, it strips out the links within the content.

**My Thoughts / Desired Results**

I'm using jQuery's .text() method to get the exact length of the description to keep slicing consistency throughout. If I am thinking right, .text() just grabs the raw content which is why the anchor tags are being stripped out. However, if I used the .html() method it would be difficult to keep that consistency of where the text is sliced at (which I need), because it will count the characters of those html tags and their attributes as well. This is where I'm kind of stuck at.

Ultimately, I would like a way to slice the description at exactly 100 characters while keeping the links in. I will also have multiple descriptions on each page so I would like a way to expand and minimize each individual unique description on click.

Play around on CodePen: https://codepen.io/andrewgarrison/pen/BdJQGz/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var minimized_elements = $('p.description');
    var minimize_character_count = 99;

    minimized_elements.each(function () {
        var t = $(this).text();
        if (t.length < minimize_character_count) return;

        $(this).html(
            t.slice(0, minimize_character_count) 
          + '<span>... </span><a href="#" class="more">More</a>'
          + '<span style="display:none;">'
          + t.slice(minimize_character_count, t.length) + ' <a href="#" class="less">Less</a></span>'
        );

    });

    $('a.more', minimized_elements).click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide().prev().hide();
        $(this).next().show();
    });

    $('a.less', minimized_elements).click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Sliced Text</h3>
<p class="description">This product is super hot. You can go to <a href="http://www.someurlgoeshere.org">this awesome website</a> and order it right now! But wait, that's not all. If you buy three you get 20 more free. That's right. Buy now from <a href="#">here</a> and this could all be yours.</p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using CSS to hide anything wider/taller than a given pixel (or other unit) width? That way you wouldn't need to modify the actual content of the element at all.

Comment: Yeah I have, I probably should have clarified that the reason I am truncating the text is because I don't want the 'preview' to go past two lines within a 300px width div that I will be using it in. Therefore, I also need the "More" link to be on the second line because I don't have room to put it below. If I did I would definitely use a CSS based approach. Thank you for the response and thought!

Comment: use .children('a') to grab the links and then map over them making an array of the links and another of the anchor text. I'm thinking you'll replace the text from the link arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery contents function to obtain a list of children of an element, including text nodes.

Then you can loop over the children and add them until the character count is over the maximum. But instead of putting the rest inside a span here I am just duplicating the paragraph and toggling between both. If the split happens inside the link (e.g. if you set `minimize_character_count` to 50) only part of the link will show but it will still work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var minimized_elements = $('p.description');
    var maxchars = 99;

    minimized_elements.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.hide();
      var children = $this.contents();
      var $shortDesc = $('<div />');
      var len = children.length;
      var count = 0;
      var i = 0;
      while (i < len) {
        var $elem = $(children[i]).clone();
        var text = $elem.text();
        var l = text.length;
        if (count + l > maxchars) {
          var newText = text.slice(0, maxchars - count);
          if ($elem.get(0).nodeType === 3) {
            $elem = document.createTextNode(newText);
          } else {
            $elem.text(newText);
          }
          $shortDesc.append($elem);
          break;
        }
        count += l;
        $shortDesc.append($elem);
        i++;
      }
      $shortDesc.append($('<span>... </span>'));

      $shortDesc.append($('<a href="#" class="more">More</a>').on('click', function(){
        $this.show();
        $shortDesc.hide();
      }));
      $this.append($('<a href="#" class="less">Less</a>').on('click', function() {
        $this.hide();
        $shortDesc.show();
      }));

      $this.after($shortDesc);
    });
});
```

Here's the demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eEyvpY?editors=1011

Comment: I like the approach, however, it doesn't correctly slice the string at an exact point. For instance, if you set the minimize_character_count at 99 it shows 174 characters. Ultimately, I used Siah's technique to correctly slice and leave the links in and did some rework on how I toggle the More and Less links.

Comment: Oh you are right, It seems like jQuery can't update the text in textNodes. I'll update the answer anyway. Edit: done

Comment: I'm actually leaning more towards your answer after the update - thank you for taking to time to revise it... I'm now having issues handling multiple descriptions on the same page and opening and closing each unique one individually. Any idea how I can handle this?

Comment: It was missing a `var` in line 6.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have managed to achieve what you're looking to do here: https://codepen.io/hydrospell/pen/EvoZbB

The steps I took were:

1. Record all the `<a>` occurrences with their text, url and index
   in the original string and collect them in an array
2. Truncate string without considering HTML (`.text()`)
3. Walk through the array of links, substituting in the links for each linked text with the help of the collected indices. There is a consideration for if the last link needs to be truncated as well.

I hope this helps!

*This is my first stackoverflow answer, so please forgive any formatting/linking etiquette faux pas!*